# QtSql convert MySql queries to SQLite

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I am trying to convert some MySql queries to SQLite using Python PyQt, but I cannot seem to get it working. When I run the following code, nothing prints out, no errors or results. What is wrong with the code?

```
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
db.setDatabaseName("TEST")
if not db.open():
    QMessageBox.warning(None,  "Database",  
                        QString("Database Error: %1").arg(db.lastError().text()))
    sys.exit(1)

query = QSqlQuery()

query.exec_("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CollectStatus (
                        id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
                        status TEXT  NOT NULL ,
                        PRIMARY KEY (id) ,
                        UNIQUE INDEX status_UNIQUE (status ASC) );""")

query.exec_("INSERT INTO CollectStatus (status) VALUES (1)")
query.exec_("SELECT status FROM CollectStatus")
while query.next():
    print(query.value(status).toString()[0])

db.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to commit in SQLite. Apparently PyQt does not give an error when there is a problem with the SQL syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know PyQT, but when you're using the native sqlite bindings, you have to issue

```
conn.commit()
```

when you actually want to commit your changes to the database. So you'd need the PyQT version of that after your `insert` and before your `select`.

A quick glance at the docs makes it look like the PyQT version is

```
db.commit()
```

Comment: even after doing that, I am still seeing the database file being 0 bytes in size.

Comment: You would need the commit to see the result *across* transactions, but on the same connection, the inserted data should be present anyway.